# How to make a string consecutive

Tags: excel, vba, string

I have the following string representing a contiguous value or consecutive
CGF00000001
The value must go in the following way:

```
CGF00000001,CGF00000002...CGF99999999(reached this point it must continue like the second line)
CGG00000001,CGG00000002...CGG99999999(reached this point it must continue like the third line)
CGH00000001,CGH00000002...CGH99999999 and so on , until reaching the form of the last line shown
ZZZ00000001,ZZZ00000002,ZZZ99999999... At this point the system must return an error.
```

Comment: I'm using VBA for now in Excel

Comment: I only have a basic code not working

Comment: Including your code in your question would be quite helpful.

Comment: Where the strings in discussion to be placed? Should they stay in memory? Why "At this point the system must return an error"? Please, explain you really try accomplishing. It may be helpful. Besides your code, even if it does not do what you need...

Comment: Strings must be assigned to a variable, when the algoritm reaches the maximum allowed value it must return an error.

Comment: What kind of error and **why**, instead of simple code exit? When you say "I have the following string", what do you mean by that? Do you have it or you want building it? I asked you in my previous comment about what you want accomplishing, supposing that we will better understand your question. Can you answer this question, please? Since you talk about 'lines', should all the huge lines be part of huge string, having the lines separated by line end?

Comment: The string is from another system, I don't control the format. I must make the string and the numeric part incremental. The following line is like an example , when you get to the first XXX99999 value, it must continue like the second line, the second and next lines are only examples of how  the value must increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a TextBox contains your starting value here is some code showing how to increment that value:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Text1.Text = IncrementValue(Text1.Text)
End Sub

Private Function IncrementValue(ByVal Value As String) As String
   Dim prefix As String
   Dim suffix As Long
   
   prefix = Mid(Value, 1, 3)
   suffix = CLng(Mid(Value, 4))
   
   If prefix = "ZZZ" And suffix = 99999999 Then
      IncrementValue = "error" 'do whatever you need
      Exit Function
   End If
   
   If suffix = 99999999 Then
      prefix = NumberToLetters(LettersToNumber(prefix) + 1)
      suffix = 0
   End If
   
   suffix = suffix + 1
   IncrementValue = prefix & Format(suffix, "00000000")
End Function

Private Function LettersToNumber(ByVal Letters As String) As Integer
   Dim i As Integer

   For i = 1 To Len(Letters)
      LettersToNumber = LettersToNumber * 26 + (Asc(Mid(Letters, i, 1)) - 64)
   Next
End Function

Private Function NumberToLetters(ByVal Number As Integer) As String
   Dim modulo As Integer
    
   Do While Number > 0
      modulo = (Number - 1) Mod 26
      NumberToLetters = Chr(65 + modulo) & NumberToLetters
      Number = CInt((Number - modulo) / 26)
   Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Very nice algorithm/logic! Voted up. But I am afraid that it will freeze any computer trying to continuously iterate in order to obtain the huge string required in the (strange) question...

Comment: I don't think the OP is saying to build a single huge string.  Rather, the OP is showing how the values should progress.

Comment: At least, this is what I understood from "the following string representing a contiguous value or consecutive CGF00000001". But I can admit I may be wrong...

Comment: First, thanks Brian. Your answer is very good.  I only expanded it a litlle.
But I don't know how to post full code like you

Comment: I Upvote, but my points are too low to mark as solved